# How to fix this code written in Xcode? In the main function, Xcode is displaying the error:Function definition is not allowed here

Tags: c, xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x, int y) {

  for (int i = 10; i > 5; i--) {

    if (x % i == 0) {

      y = x ^ 3;
      printf("x is %d and y is %d\n", x, y);
      return x + y;
    }

    else {

      y = x + 1;
      printf("x is %d and y is %d\n", x, y);
      return x * y;
    }
  }

  int main() { // I am getting error on this line.Function definition is not
               // allowed here.
    int a = f(30, 10);
    int b = f(20, 5);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Xcode displays this as a parse issue. please help me fix this code.

Comment: You can't define a function inside another one.

Comment: @Sparsh Gupta The reason of the error is the bad programming style. Place braces always under each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems within your code is,

1. Here the closing brace `}` of `int f(int x, int y)` is missing. Please check my comments inside the code itself.
2. One more closing brace `}` is added at the end of your program which is not required.

The corrected code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x, int y) {

  for (int i = 10; i > 5; i--) {

    if (x % i == 0) {

      y = x ^ 3;
      printf("x is %d and y is %d\n", x, y);
      return x + y;
    } //Closing brace of 'if' condition
    else {

      y = x + 1;
      printf("x is %d and y is %d\n", x, y);
      return x * y;
    } //Closing brace of 'else' condition

  } //Closing brace of for-loop

} //Here add the closing brace of 'int f(int x, inty)'

int main() {
  int a = f(30, 10);
  int b = f(20, 5);
  return 0;
} //Removed the last '}' in your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `}` to end function `f()`. So by mistake you placed `main()` inside the function `f()`.